# Why is running UNIONS so slow in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am running a simple select * with three UNIONS across 3 data extensions with only 8 fields each and it takes forever to run, like 5 minutes. Should I make three separate queries instead and run them concurrently? What gives with the UNION slowness?

DEs: 8 fields
Number
Text/128
Number
Text/8
Text/50
EmailAddress
EmailAddress
Date

Column count: <100 in any one DE, <200 across all 3

What it's essentially doing is pulling the recipient lists of three different emails and adding them to a single daily log. This log gets referenced to determine which email should be sent.

Comment: Is this question about marketing cloud?

Comment: Yes - sorry about that!

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you were on the proper forum. :)

Comment: How large are your DEs?  And what data types are your keys?  Maybe you could update your question with your query?

Comment: Small row count. We're talking <100 in each DE and <200 total. Good idea I'll update the question

Comment: If you need UNION you're forcing SQL Server to return distinct rows (expensive). If you need UNION ALL, that would be quicker in a very small way, but is a faster query to execute. More likely the "issue" you're having is the inherent latency built into the way Query Activities are executed. When you hit run, the query's sent off to a queue that's eventually picked up by a slot server to execute. You may find the queue takes a 4:59 to get through and the query executes in under a second.

Comment: I would make 3 queries. In practice I have found using seperate queries is best. Issue with unions on big data sets is that they can timeout.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you on big datasets @mattcameron Break everything down into tiny parts is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unions are computationally expensive. This is because in SQL server , a simple union does 2 queries and concatenates them. In addition to this, it performs a "sort" operation, so that there are no duplicate records (i.e if a contact exists in  both A & B, return A).

A "Union All" will speed things up significantly as it will not perform the "distinct" operation and WILL return duplicates.

Comment: Agree somewhat, if we were talking about larger datasets. SQL Server will process either a UNION ALL or a plain UNION on this data in milliseconds. The difference in speed would be imperceptible. The main "issue" isn't around SQL tuning, but rather the time it takes the slot servers to pick up the job and execute that 5ms query. The queue to the slot servers isn't in our control and it's just what it is.

Comment: The queue been out of our control is a problem that is not just unique to UNION. As this question refers to UNION and not general T-SQL functionality on SFMC, I think addressing query optimisation is the way forward. Adding staging tables would definitely boost performance.

Comment: Adding staging tables for a tiny dataset, like this, would slow down your automation with multiple sub-second queries each taking five minutes. The question was "why are unions taking so long to execute?" The answer is they aren't taking any perceivable time longer than other queries in this instance. Grab some tables with a few million records in each and then the answer is different.